# OutputTooSmallUTxO error

Tags: native-assets

I'm following these [steps](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/#fund-the-address) and I get the OutputTooSmallUTxO error.
Not sure what I missed from the steps but here's my parameters and the error as a whole.

tokenname1="Testtoken"
tokenname2="SecondTesttoken"
tokenamount="100000000"
output="0"

fee="300000"
txhash="8a7e45c02cf25cb1b9870fbcc87b61d61cefb514ccfb960bcc7651023ea7ffb2"
txix="0"
funds="1000000000"
policyid=$(cat policy/policyID)

cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
--fee $fee 
--tx-in "$txhash#$txix" 
--tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname1 + $tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname2" 
--mint="$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname1 + $tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname2" 
--minting-script-file policy/policy.script 
--out-file matx.raw

fee=$(cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee --tx-body-file matx.raw --tx-in-count 1 --tx-out-count 1 --witness-count 1 --testnet-magic 1097911063 --protocol-params-file protocol.json | cut -d " " -f1) (This was not incluted in the tutorial and i added it from a block post i found here in reference to a similar issue)

cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
--fee $fee 
--tx-in "$txhash#$txix" 
--tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname1 + $tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname2" 
--mint="$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname1 + $tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname2" 
--minting-script-file policy/policy.script 
--out-file matx.raw

cardano-cli transaction sign  
--signing-key-file payment.skey  
--signing-key-file policy/policy.skey  
--testnet-magic 1097911063 --tx-body-file matx.raw  
--out-file matx.signed

cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file matx.signed --testnet-magic 1097911063

Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (OutputTooSmallUTxO [(Addr Testnet (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "63c7e6f65c0185e0afa19657977c86e663873143569b665d23f532ea")) StakeRefNull,Value 0 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "68d7df6ec365f5d9885c451e58e8994741c1970211c01843703f6136"},fromList [("SecondTesttoken",100000000),("Testtoken",100000000)])]),SNothing)]))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 1000000000 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "68d7df6ec365f5d9885c451e58e8994741c1970211c01843703f6136"},fromList [("SecondTesttoken",100000000),("Testtoken",100000000)])])) (Value 177601 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "68d7df6ec365f5d9885c451e58e8994741c1970211c01843703f6136"},fromList [("SecondTesttoken",100000000),("Testtoken",100000000)])])))))])
antonis@adastp:~/tokens$ echo $cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file matx.signed --testnet-magic 1097911063^C

--tx-in
addr_test1vp3u0ehktsqctc905xt909musmnx8pe3gdtfkejay06n96shpzd3t+0+100000000 68d7df6ec365f5d9885c451e58e8994741c1970211c01843703f6136.Testtoken + 100000000 68d7df6ec365f5d9885c451e58e8994741c1970211c01843703f6136.SecondTesttoken

--tx-out
8a7e45c02cf25cb1b9870fbcc87b61d61cefb514ccfb960bcc7651023ea7ffb2#0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't account for change return value (your `$output` variable which is zero).

Your transaction spends some UTxO to pay the fee but the rest of this UTxOs ADA has to go somewhere (hence the `value not conserved` error).

I think you need to look up the ADA value of the `--tx-in "$txhash#$txix"` (your `$funds` variable?) and subtract fee from it, which is the unspent ADA you get back.

Comment: Thanks I was missing the output=$(expr $funds - $fee)

Comment: Nice! Please mark the question as answered :-)